# Isomorphism type of mapping class group

Tags: mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

Let $MCG(S_{g,b}^s)$ be the mapping class group of a surface $S_{g,b}^s$. Assume that it is not trivial.

Is it true that $MCG(S_{g,b}^s)$ is isomorphic to $MCG(S_{g',b'}^{s'})$ if and only if $ S_{g,b}^s$ is homeomorphic to $S_{g',b'}^{s'}$ ? 
Or what is the complete list of counterexamples?

Comment: Aren't the mapping class group of the $2$-sphere and the $2$-disk both trivial?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1666775